# Не завершается программа после выполнения потока - C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Не завершается программа после выполнения второго потока.

Я понял, что виноват цикл внутри метода, который выполняется вторым потоком. Я могу его убрать и все будет работать нормально. Но мне по заданию для второго потока нужно выводить в файл информацию до тех пор, пока не пройдет какое-то время. Время в секундах я задаю в TimeSpan в Join для этого потока.

На консоли появляются сообщения "Поток 1 завершен" и "Работа потоков выполнена." Дальше просто мигает "каретка" консоли, а при завершении программы не появляется стандартное сообщение, призывающее нажать любую клавишу для выхода (очевидно, потому что она не завершается).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        Table1 ta1 = new Table1(x1, s1, d1);
        Table2 ta2 = new Table2(x2, s2, d2);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Method1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Method2));
        thread1.Start(ta1);
        thread2.Start(ta2);
        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join(new TimeSpan(0, 0, t2));
        Console.WriteLine("Работа потоков выполнена.");
    }

    static void Method1(object data)
    {
        Table1 t = (Table1)data;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Thread1.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string output = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + "  " +
                    string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", t.X) + "  " + string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", Math.Log(t.X, Math.E)) + '\n';
                fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), 0, output.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(t.D);
                t.X += t.S;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Поток 1 завершен.");
        }
    }

    static void Method2(object data)
    {
        Table2 t = (Table2)data;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Thread2.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
            {
                string output = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + "  " +
                        string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", t.X) + "  " + string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", Math.Log(t.X, Math.E)) + '\n';
                fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), 0, output.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(t.D);
                t.X += t.S;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ta1`, `x1, s1, d1`, `t2`, `t.X += t.S;` люблю такие названия, просто сказка, потому, что далее уже не хочется разбираться с этим кодом.

Comment: Ставьте потокам IsBackground=true, чтобы они помирали вместе с основным потоком.

Comment: @Bulson, это всего лишь переменные, значение которых знать в данном случае в принципе не нужно. `t2` - количество секунд, что уже понятно из `TimeSpan`. Все остальное, что находится внутри циклов роли не должно играть. Ну, кроме `Sleep(t.D)` наверное. Но сразу говорю, значение я ставлю не большое.

Comment: @tym32167, да , это помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас время в TimeSpan будет работать не от запуска обоих потоков а от момента окончания работы первого потока.

Comment: В программе есть дефект, если поток насильно прервётся в момент записи файла, файл может оказаться битым, либо в нём может непойми что записаться.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, я решил сразу после записи в файл выводить эту строку на консоль, и оказалось, что поток как раз таки не прерывался. Даже после `thread2.Join(new TimeSpan(0, 0, t2));` поток продолжал выполнение (я поменял местами `Join`'ы), и цикл все так же работал. Мне пришлось ввести логическую переменную и изменять ее извне, поэтому итерация полностью заканчивается, и, мне кажется, данные в файл будут записываться без ошибок.

Comment: Условие `while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)` не имеет никакого смысла. IsAlive возвращает false, только когда поток уже не работает. С таким же успехом могло быть `while(true)`

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии предложен вариант решения, но это решение имеет дефект.

Если вы насильно прекращаете работу потока по завершению программы, то запись в файл может пройти некорректно, и в файл могут либо попасть инвалидные данные, или даже файл может запороться.

Поэтому делаем другую логику метода, в приведённом коде итерация цикла второго метода обязательно завершится, и метод прервёт работу на очередной итерации по завершению времени.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        Table1 ta1 = new Table1(x1, s1, d1);
        Table2 ta2 = new Table2(x2, s2, d2);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Method1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Method2));
        thread1.Start(ta1);
        thread2.Start(new object[] {ta2, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20)});
        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Работа потоков выполнена.");
    }

    static void Method1(object data)
    {
        Table1 t = (Table1)data;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Thread1.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string output = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + "  " +
                    string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", t.X) + "  " + string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", Math.Log(t.X, Math.E)) + '\n';
                fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), 0, output.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(t.D);
                t.X += t.S;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Поток 1 завершен.");
        }
    }

    static void Method2(object data)
    {
        Table2 t = (Table2)((object[])data)[0];
        DateTime end = (DateTime)((object[])data)[1];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Thread2.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            while (DateTime.Now <= end)
            {
                string output = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + "  " +
                        string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", t.X) + "  " + string.Format("{0:0000.0000}", Math.Log(t.X, Math.E)) + '\n';
                fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), 0, output.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(t.D);
                t.X += t.S;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае передаю во второй метод параметры через массив.
Есть другие альтернативы, возможно более красивые.

1. Создать специальный класс параметров для этого
2. Либо использовать класс Tuple

Мне наиболее нравится второй вариант, что бы не засорять пространство лишними классами.

Comment: не лучше ли тогда уже токен отмены передавать?

Comment: @tym32167 наверное это зависит от того из какого места и потока мы хотим прерывать наш поток. На самом деле по условию это не понятно, не хватает данных, непонятен контекст использования этих функций.

Comment: @tym32167 если у вас есть решение с токеном отмены, то буду рад его увидеть ответом.

Comment: не, я, пожалуй, пас :)